# AWS Permissions for Cross-Account DNS Association

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, permissions

*Summary: I've got permissions issues associating a private DNS Hosted Zone across accounts in the same AWS region*

I have two AWS accounts, and in each I've created a VPC and servers etc. The first account (11112222) provides some services from a private subnet, with a private DNS Hosted Zone etc.

I'd like to provide DNS lookups of the services on my private subnet to my second account (22223333) which has a 'project' VPC and servers in it. I have created a Peering Connection from the project to the services VPC, and have accepted it on the services VPC side, setup routes, etc.

For DNS, I have created an Association Authorisation by running this command:

`aws route53 create-vpc-association-authorization --hosted-zone-id Z333AEF1GGC --vpc VPCRegion=eu-west-1,VPCId=vpc-012345678`

I can verify that it's done something with the `list-vpc-association-authorizations`.

Over on the 'services' VPC, I'm struggling to 'accept' the association. I'm running:

`aws route53 associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone --hosted-zone-id Z333AEF1GGC --vpc VPCRegion=eu-west-1,VPCId=vpc-abcdef01234`

However, this says:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssociateVPCWithHostedZone operation: User: arn:aws:sts::22223333:assumed-role/devops/ralph is not authorized to perform: route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone on resource: arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/Z333AEF1GGC`

Obviously I did a load of googling and found https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=243780 which says I also need ec2:DescribeVPCs. Our account permissions are fairly simple, in so much as my assumed role has "Allow *" on it (and just a few Denies for some IAM operations). I've tried to explicitly add in the two permissions, with and without specifically naming the hosted zone ARN. Nothing seems to work though.

I feel like I must be missing something pretty obvious here - any ideas what it might be? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**Additional Information (due to comments)**

- We use 2FA for all our user accounts, and then 'assume' a role to perform any actions on our accounts (assuming a role requires 2FA authentication). There are no technical requirements to use 2FA though. Our individual user accounts have almost no permissions to do anything directly.

Comment: Your usage is correct. Have you verified that you use an AWS profile in the account 22223333?

Are there additional limitations in place, e.g. the necessity for a MFA enabled session to associate a VPC? This could possible result in this error message.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help on this. I think we can put this down to "user error". My mistake was:

`aws route53 associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone --hosted-zone-id Z333AEF1GGC --vpc VPCRegion=eu-west-1,VPCId=vpc-012345678`

...should have in fact been:

`aws route53 associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone --hosted-zone-id Z333AEF1GGC --vpc VPCRegion=eu-west-1,VPCId=vpc-abcdef01234`

I'd used the HZ-side's VPC ID in the command, where [the instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/private-hosted-zone-different-account/) do indeed say to use the “account B” (ie. the 'remote' side). I'd even managed to anonymise the commands in the question correctly. I feel a bit silly now ;-(

Comment: Had come across a similar issue, I don't have the 2FA as well, But still unable to create the route association.

Tried your command as well, But no hope..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have made the same mistake as Ralph, but I will endeavor to better explain it.

For *both* the `create-vpc-association-authorization` and `associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone` commands you need to use *the same* values for `--hosted-zone-id` [the source zone ID you want to share] *and* `--vpc` [the *destination* VPC].

The only thing that differs should be the credentials.

The thing that I did wrong, that I think is an easy trap to fall in, is assume that the VPC in the source account mattered at all in this. Because it does not.

eg, using account profiles:

```
aws --profile source_account \
  route53 create-vpc-association-authorization \
  --hosted-zone-id Z00000000000000012345 \
  --vpc VPCRegion=us-west-2,VPCId=vpc-000000000000asdf

aws --profile destination_account \
  route53 associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone \
  --hosted-zone-id Z00000000000000012345 \
  --vpc VPCRegion=us-west-2,VPCId=vpc-000000000000asdf
```

Where `Z00000000000000012345` belongs to `source_account`, and `vpc-000000000000asdf` belongs to `destination_account`.

Think of it as the source account asking "Can I please attach my zone to your VPC?" and the destination answering "Yes, you can attach that zone to my VPC.".

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, thanks.